# TensorForestEstimator with feature_column throws TypeError

Tags: python, csv, numpy, classification, tflearn

I plan to use the `TensorForestEstimator` on a larger data set that will be fed through an `input_fn` that operates on Pandas objects.

To verify my understanding of the API, I put together a smaller example that uses a data set from the [UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Immunotherapy+Dataset).  The data set has seven features (six `int32`s and a `float32`) and a label (`int32`).

I can run a `fit()` and `evaluate()` just fine when the data set is fed as `numpy` arrays directly with the `x` and `y` arguments.

When I attempt to perform the same operation with data sourced from an `input_fn` that uses the from `tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn` and supply `tf.contrib.layers` feature columns to the `feature_columns` argument, I observe a value error in `tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/python/ops/data_ops.py`:

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of '_RealValuedColumn' and 'str'`

This is because `sorted()` is being called on a a list of dictionary keys that are both `str` and TensorFlow objects.

The code, exported from a Jupyter notebook, is given at the end of this post.

Any insights into why this might be happening would be appreciated.  I've done quite a bit of searching through the docs, StackOverflow, and the GitHub issue records and have yet to zero in on the root cause.

Thanks in advance!

## Sample Code for `TensorForestEstimator` with `pandas_input_fn`

### Python Standard Library Imports

```py
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
```

### TensorFlow Library Imports

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers
import tensorflow.contrib.tensor_forest as tforest
```

### Aliased TensorFlow Library Imports

```py
from tensorflow.estimator.inputs import pandas_input_fn
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
```

### Metadata for CSV Columns

```py
COLUMN_PROPS = {
    'sex' : {
        'is_feature' : True,
        'is_label' : False,
        'dtype' : tf.int32,
        'default' : -1,
        'feature_column' : layers.real_valued_column(
            'sex',
            dtype=tf.int32
        )
    },
    'age' : {
        'is_feature' : True,
        'is_label' : False,
        'dtype' : tf.int32,
        'default' : -1,
        'feature_column' : layers.real_valued_column(
            'age',
            dtype=tf.int32
        )  
    },
    'Time' : {
        'is_feature' : True,
        'is_label' : False,
        'dtype' : tf.float32,
        'default' : -1.0,
        'feature_column' : layers.real_valued_column(
            'Time',
            dtype=tf.float32
        )
    },
    'Number_of_Warts' : {
        'is_feature' : True,
        'is_label' : False,
        'dtype' : tf.int32,
        'default' : -1,
        'feature_column' : layers.real_valued_column(
            'Number_of_Warts',
            dtype=tf.int32
        ),
    },
    'Type' : {
        'is_feature' : True,
        'is_label' : False,
        'dtype' : tf.int32,
        'default' : -1,
        'feature_column' : layers.real_valued_column(
            'Type',
            dtype=tf.int32
        )
    },
    'Area' : {
        'is_feature' : True,
        'is_label' : False,
        'dtype' : tf.int32,
        'default' : -1,
        'feature_column' : layers.real_valued_column(
            'Area',
            dtype=tf.int32
        )
    },
    'induration_diameter' : {
        'is_feature' : True,
        'is_label' : False,
        'dtype': tf.int32,
        'default': -1,
        'feature_column' : layers.real_valued_column(
            'induration_diameter',
            dtype=tf.int32
        )
    },
    'Result_of_Treatment': {
        'is_feature' : False,
        'is_label' : True,
        'dtype': tf.int32,
        'default': -1,
        'feature_column' : None
    }
}
```

### Ordering of CSV Columns

```py
CSV_COLUMNS = [
    'sex',
    'age',
    'Time',
    'Number_of_Warts',
    'Type',
    'Area',
    'induration_diameter',
    'Result_of_Treatment'
]
```

### Generate Lists of Features and Labels from Metadata

```py
FEATURE_COLUMNS = []
LABEL_COLUMN = None

for k in CSV_COLUMNS:
    if COLUMN_PROPS[k]['is_feature']:
        FEATURE_COLUMNS.append(k)
    elif COLUMN_PROPS[k]['is_label']:
        LABEL_COLUMN = k
```

### Helper Function for Shuffling and Exporting Subsets

This function is used to export training, evaluation, and test data sets as CSVs, shuffling the rows.

```py
def generate_sets(datasets):
    for k, v in datasets.items():
        random.shuffle(v)
        with open(k + '.csv', 'w') as fobj:
            wrtr = csv.writer(fobj)
            wrtr.writerow(header)
            for rec in v:
                wrtr.writerow(rec)
```

### Split Datasets for Traning, Evaluation, and Testing

```py
trn = []
evl = []
tst = []

with open('Immunotherapy - ImmunoDataset.csv', 'r') as fobj:
    rdr = csv.reader(fobj)
    header = next(rdr)
    label_key = header[-1]
    feature_keys = header[:-1]

    for rec in rdr:
        # Output of random number generator determines
        # which set the record will be placed.
        rn =  random.random()
        if rn < 0.6:
            trn.append(rec)
        elif rn < 0.8:
            evl.append(rec)
        else:
            tst.append(rec)

datasets = {
    'train' : trn,
    'eval' : evl,
    'test' : tst
}

generate_sets(datasets)
```

### Set up `TensorForest` Hyperparameters

```py
fhp = tforest.tensor_forest.ForestHParams(
    num_classes=2,
    num_features=7,
    regression=False
)
```

### Pluck Feature Columns from Metadata Dictionary

```py
fcs = [COLUMN_PROPS[k]['feature_column'] for k in FEATURE_COLUMNS]
```

### Instatntiate `TensorForestEstimator` Object

```py
tfe = tforest.random_forest.TensorForestEstimator(
    fhp,
    feature_columns=fcs,
    report_feature_importances=True
)
```

### Define a Wrapper for a `pandas_input_fn`

```py
def get_input_fn(csv_file):

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

    features = df.loc[:,'sex':'induration_diameter']

    # Workaround for this issue:
    #
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577372/tensorflowusing-pandas-input-fn-with-tensorforestestimator
    # https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16692

    labels = pd.DataFrame(
        np.expand_dims(
            df.loc[:,'Result_of_Treatment'].values, axis=1
        )
    )

    return pandas_input_fn(x=features, y=labels, shuffle=False)
```

### Train on Data

```py
tfe.fit(
    input_fn=get_input_fn('train.csv')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, I believe this is a bug in `TensorForestEstimator`.  More details can be found in GitHub Issue at this URL:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26082